# Is there a method using HTML elements or standard JS to have ghost text in an input field so the user can't edit it, but it's always present?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm still learning HTML/JS everyday, and for a project I'm working on, I need the user to be able to input their room details in either meters (m) or feet (ft) and the temperature they would want their room to be (°C).

I need "m"/"ft"/"°C" to show constantly at the back of the input in some form of ghost text (like placeholder, but doesn't disappear). While the user inputs numbers into the field, the "m"/"ft"/"°C" should move to the back and when the user clicks on the input field the typing should start at the front.

```
<td class="Table_Cell" id="Table_Cell"> 
    <input class="Input_Boxes" id="Width" maxlength="10" onchange="Update_Room_Inputs()" onclick="Check_Focus(this)" value="m">
    <div class="Rooms_Input_Label"><p>Width</p></div>
</td>
<td class="Table_Cell" id="Table_Cell">
    <input class="Input_Boxes" id="Depth" maxlength="10" onchange="Update_Room_Inputs()" onclick="Check_Focus(this)" value="m">
    <div class="Rooms_Input_Label"><p>Depth</p></div>
</td>
<td class="Table_Cell" id="Table_Cell">
    <input class="Input_Boxes" id="Height" maxlength="10" onchange="Update_Room_Inputs()" onclick="Check_Focus(this)" value="m">
    <div class="Rooms_Input_Label"><p>Height</p></div>
</td>
<td class="Table_Cell" id="Table_Cell">
    <input class="Input_Boxes" id="Temperature" maxlength="10" onchange="Update_Room_Inputs()" onclick="Check_Focus(this)" value="°C">
    <div class="Rooms_Input_Label"><p>Temperature (°C)</p></div>
</td>
```

This is the HTML I currently have for the input fields. The JS functions aren't important for the question. The JS code currently allows for user inputs and then duplicates the table of inputs for the users to input another room.

Comment: `<input type="text" value="I'm your ghost" readonly>` - Also, stop using HTML inline JS `on*` handlers. JS should be in one place only, and that's its respective tag or file. Use Element.addEventListener() isntead.

Comment: I guess OP wants to add something like currency to the input, but the temperature symbol in this example

Comment: FWIW not having placeholder text disappear when filling in an input field doesn't seem great DX.

Comment: We have the text disappear currently, however, we've had users complain that they try to reinput the letters/symbols and they end up breaking it. So, we need to prevent this from happening...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
let symbol = "°C";

document.querySelector("input").onkeydown = (e) => {
    let inputValue = e.currentTarget.value;
    let selectionStart = e.currentTarget.selectionStart;
    let testKeys = /ArrowLeft|ArrowRight|Backspace/.test(e.key);
    if (
        (inputValue.indexOf(".") >= 0 && e.key === ".") ||
        (/[^1-9.]+/.test(e.key) && !testKeys) ||
        (selectionStart > inputValue.length - symbol.length && !testKeys)
    ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
};

document.querySelector("input").onclick = (e) => {
    let inputValue = e.currentTarget.value;
    if (e.currentTarget.selectionStart > inputValue.length - symbol.length) {
        let start = inputValue.length - symbol.length;
        e.currentTarget.setSelectionRange(start, start);
    }
};
document.querySelector("input").oninput = (e) => {
    if (e.data === ".") return;
    e.currentTarget.value =
        e.currentTarget.value.match(/(\d+\.\d*)|(\d+)/)[0] + symbol;
};
```

```html
<input value="°C"/>
```